# discrete probability distributions; Dish problem

Tags: probability

A restaurant has 3 fish dishes, 6 meat dishes and 5 vegetarian dishes on the menu. Suppose that customers select their dish at random. Five customers enter the restaurant.
Note that more than one customer can have the same dish.

a) What is the probability that the first customer chooses a vegetarian and two fish dishes are chosen?

b)What is the probability that two customers choose a fish dish given that only one customer chooses a vegetarian dish?

c)What is the probability that the first customer orders a fish and the second, a vegetarian?

Very interested in how probability distribution can be used in solving these, my current approach was the conventional use of combinations and permutations but not getting the correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

The probability distribution of fish, meat, and vegetarian dishes among five customers has generating function

$$ \left( {{3 f + 6 m + 5 v} \over {3 + 6 + 5}} \right) ^5 $$

So $\ldots$

Comment: thanks mate, now where exactly would I go from there?

Comment: @Mondli.K You can work out (c) directly. (b) is the coefficient of $ f ^ 2 m ^ ? v ^ 1 $ in the given generating function. (a) is the product of the probability of choosing a vegetarian and the probability of two customers *from four* choosing fish. You can adapt the generating function by coalescing $m$ and $v$ into $x$, say, then looking for the coefficient of $ f ^ 2 x ^ 2$ in the *fourth* power.